# Can you filter with in a groupby function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, counting

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I was wondering if it is possible to filter with in a groupby function in pandas and the reason why is because I want to find out for each gender what is the total number of mobile users. In my dataset we have a Boolean column named mobile where if a customer is mobile it would be considered True and False if not. We a Gender column which is a string data type which lets us know the gender of a customer such as male, female and other. I also have a customer column which is a string data type also and what I am trying to do is get the total number of mobile customers for each gender. This is what my code looked like to get what I am trying to get:

`df.groupby('gender')[df['mobile'] == True]['customer'].count()`

But this piece of code didn't work. Could someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't, filter **before** the groupby:

```
df[df['mobile'] == True].groupby('gender')['customer'].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your dataframe first then use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) instead of `groupby_count`:

```
df[df['mobile'] == True].value_counts(subset=['gender', 'customer'])

# OR

df.loc[df['mobile'] == True, ['gender', 'customer']).value_counts()
```

If you really have a boolean column (`bool` dtype) you can remove `== True` from the condition.